# Sonata Admin bundle Doing a One to Many to One join results in a null pointer in the first One-Many join

Tags: sonata-admin

I have a One To Many To One relationship between Page, PageMedia and Sonata Media Bundles Media class.
I get the insert into the PageMedia and Page but for some reason the page id in the page media table always comes up null.

Here are the relevent parts of my Objects I am trying to work with.

```
class Page {
   /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PageMedia", mappedBy="page", cascade={"persist"} */
   protected $pageMedias;
}

class PageMedia {
   /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="pageMedias") ) */
   protected $page;

   /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"}) */
   protected $media;
}

 class PageAdmin extends Admin {
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form) {
      $form
        ->with('Media')
             ->add('pageMedias', 'sonata_type_collection', 
                  array('by_reference' => false ), array(
                 'edit'=>'inline',
                 'inline' => 'table',
                 'sortable' => 'sortOrder'
               ))
        ->end();
    }
}

class PageMediaAdmin extends Admin {
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form) {
    $form->add('media', 'sonata_type_model_list',
                    array(),
            array('link_parameters'=>array('context' =>'default')));
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me solve the problem?  I am at an utter loss here... Even after adding a fale nullable to the joinColumn between page and page media now I cannot insert, what did I miss?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In your Page class, you should have a "addPageMedia" method...like this:

```
$this->pageMedias[] = $pageMedia;
```

you have to add this before

```
$pageMedia->setPage($this)
```

or something similar! :)